# How to use Groovy JsonOutput.toJson with data encoded with UTF-8?

Tags: json, unicode, encoding, groovy, utf-8

I have a file with UTF-8 encoding.

I write a groovy script to load a file with a JSON structure, modify it and save it:

```
def originPreviewFilePath = "./xxx.json"

//target the file
def originFile = new File(originPreviewFilePath) 

//load the UTF8 data file as a JSON structure
def originPreview = new JsonSlurper().parse(originFile,'UTF-8')

//Here is my own code to modify originPreview

 //Convert the structure to JSON Text
def resultPreviewJson = JsonOutput.toJson(originPreview) 

//Beautify JSON Text (Indent)
def finalFileData = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(resultPreviewJson) 

//save the JSONText
new File(resultPreviewFilePath).write(finalFileData, 'UTF-8')
```

The problem is that `JsonOutput.toJson` transforms UTF-8 data to UNICODE. I don't understand why `JsonSlurper().parse` can use UTF-8 but not `JsonOutput.toJson`?

How to have `JsonOutput.toJson` use UTF-8? I need to have the exact inverse of `JsonSlurper().parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the encoding is applied at the incorrect statement while reading itself.

**Change below statements from :**

```
def originFile = new File(originPreviewFilePath)
def originPreview = new JsonSlurper().parse(originFile,'UTF-8')
```

**To:**

```
def originFile = new File(originPreviewFilePath).getText('UTF-8')
def originPreview = new JsonSlurper().parseText(originFile)
```

Comment: This has no effect. The problem is that `JsonOutput.toJson` uses unicode regardless from the input.

Comment: I have same issue as Johannes - groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(["тест":"кирилиця"]) produces escaped sequences on toString() call, and so does groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(["тест":"кирилиця"]))

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone is still struggling with this, the solution is to disable unicode escaping:

```
new JsonGenerator.Options()
    .disableUnicodeEscaping()
    .build()
    .toJson(object)
```

Comment: JsonGenerator is an interface, how that works? show a full example.

Comment: @PabloPazos that is the full example. `JsonGenerator` is an interface but we are instantiating the static nested class called `Options`. See https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/JsonGenerator.Options.html for an explanation and another example.

Comment: To be complete it needs to define "object". Note: JsonGenerator is not available in Groovy 2.4.x

Comment: @ReginaldoSantos just wrap the call using `JsonOutput.prettyPrint`. The `toJson` is never meant to print prettily.

Comment: @adarshr tks for your reply, but unfortunately, JsonOutput.prettyPrint applies unicode the same way JsonOutput.toJson does. And JsonGenerator has no prettyPrint method/option.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps check if Groovy 3 has fixed this?

Comment: It doesn't work in Groovy 3. What works is surrounding the the JsonOutput.prettyPrint witth StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Groovy 3:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(
  JsonOutput.prettyPrint(resultPreviewJson)
)
```

Comment: This will unescape things that you definitely want to keep escaped, like double quotes. If you want to go this route, use UnicodeUnescaper in apache commons-text.